From the perspective of mathematical optimization, why is $B_2$ a better battery than $B_1$ even though $B_1$ has better summary statistics?
Consider two batteries being offered by BatteCo, LLC. $B_1$ offers 8 hours of use and 10 minutes of charge time until full. $B_2$ offers 8 days of use and 1 day of charge time until full.
From the perspective of duty cycle efficiency:
$B_1 = \frac{\frac{10\mathrm{min}}{60\mathrm{min}}}{8\mathrm{hours}+\frac{10\mathrm{min}}{60\mathrm{min}}} \approx 98.1\%$
$B_2 = \frac{192\mathrm{hours}}{192\mathrm{hours} + 24\mathrm{hours}} \approx 88.9\%$
From the perspective of relative charging time:
$B_1 = \frac{\frac{1}{6}}{8} \approx 2.08\%$
$B_2 = \frac{24}{192} = 12.5\%$.
So based off of summary statistics, $B_1$ is both times the better battery than $B_2$.
But from the perspective of human intuition... you would have to be insane to choose $B_1$ over $B_2$! It is obviously the better choice to get a smartphone with $B_2$ instead of $B_1$.
What gives?

What is "better" depends on non-mathematical criteria, involving in what circumstances you intend to use the battery, when you intend to charge it, etc. This is not a mathematical question.

@RobertIsrael The Axiom of Choice is an axiom of the mathematical universe, understanding sir.

In this case, it means duty cycle efficiency and relative charging time is not what we intuitively cares about the most.
As long as the duty cycle efficiency is not too low and relative charging time is not too high, most people would view it as acceptable.
An alternative objective function could be more appropriate, it could be a function of duty cycle efficiency, relative charging rate,frequency that we have to charge it and the duration between charging. We usually call such a function called utility function.
In practice, modeling could be an iterative process and we might have to reformulate multiple times until it capture some extent of reality.
